# Pygame Sound/Font/Delay seems to be out of order

Tags: python, fonts, delay, pygame, audio

I'm making a Snake type game using Pygame.  Everything's pretty much working, but below is the end of my game.  There's a sound effect, and I put in the delay so the window didn't close before the sound finished playing.  It all worked fine, and I just added in the Game Over text.  For some reason, the sound plays, the game pauses, and *then* the Game Over quickly flashes on the screen.  Can anyone explain to me why this is going out of order?

I'm using Python 2.7 on Mac 10.6.8.

```
if w.crashed or w.x<=0 or w.x >= width - 1 or w.y<=0 or w.y >= height -1:
    gameover.play()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
    end_game = font.render("Game Over!", True, (255, 0, 0), (0,0,0))
    endRect = end_game.get_rect(centerx = width/2, centery = height / 2)
    screen.blit(end_game, endRect)
    pygame.time.delay(3500)
    running = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you are missing `pygame.display.flip()` or `display.update(rectangle=endRect)` right after the `screen.blit()` call ?

Comment: Sure was!  It didn't flip until it got to the end of the while loop, long after the pause.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the `running` varibale.  If that ends your main while loop*, it ends the program, and that would be your problem.

*main while loop:

```
while running:
    #everything that the program does goes here
```

Most games have one, and doing anything to affect it would ruin the loop, and therefore end everything in your program.  Since the code you displayed in the question would be inside that loop, the text and the sound would not play.

I know it would make sense for python to pause the program when it finds the delay command, but it actually does not actually pause the program.  It just pauses *pygame*.  The program will continue running, assign `running` to `false`, and your loop just ended.  The font will not render because it is in the loop, and the sound won't play because pygame was paused.  It never un-paused because that would be an event called in the while loop, which is now closed.

As a side note, the reason Pygame keeps the "frozen" window open is because the variables for every other image and font on the screen stays the same, and it was not told to close.

Of course this whole answer could have been a waste of both of our time if the `running` variable isn't what I think it is.

A worthy question :)

Comment: Running is indeed what you expect, but the behavior isn't like you're describing.  I expected it to play the sound, display the text, pause, and close.  Instead it plays the sound, pauses, displays the text (for an instant) and closes. 

If the delay isn't the way to go, how can I leave the text on the screen while the music plays without the window instantly closing when my snake crashes?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the other answer, because I think it's the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.display.flip() should be done before `pygame.time.delay(3500)`.
```

Change your code to this

```
if w.crashed or w.x<=0 or w.x >= width - 1 or w.y<=0 or w.y >= height -1:
    gameover.play()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
    end_game = font.render("Game Over!", True, (255, 0, 0), (0,0,0))
    endRect = end_game.get_rect(centerx = width/2, centery = height / 2)
    screen.blit(end_game, endRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.delay(3500)

    running = False
```

Comment: please add explanation to your code, this will help others to understand it quickly.